# Stop animation when pause button clicked in Exoplayer Notification

Tags: android, animation, notifications, imagebutton, exoplayer

my problem is that I added an Exoplayer Notification to my app, and I want when I press the "Pause" button, to stop an animation from the MainActivity. I have an animation to an ImageButton. I know how to stop the animation under normal circumstances,
but I do not know how stop the animation from the Notification. Below I'll add you my notification code.
Thank you in advance !!!

```
notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
            this,
            CHANNEL_ID,
            R.string.exo_download_notification_channel_name,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                    return text_song;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                            (MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                    return contentPendingIntent;
                }
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                    return null; 
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {

                    return null;
                }
            }
    );
    notificationManager.setUseChronometer(true);
    notificationManager.setUseNavigationActions(false);
    notificationManager.setFastForwardIncrementMs(0);
    notificationManager.setRewindIncrementMs(0);
    notificationManager.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    notificationManager.setPlayer(player);
```

Comment: Are you also using a mediasession?

Comment: I have an Exoplayer with audio only in my app. If you mean this...

Comment: And do you already have a notification with playback controls?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: You can use a broadcastreceiver or bind your service to communicate back to the activity.